# RTL footonotes MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, right-to-left, footnote

I am using a RTl language in Word, and have set up word for this. However in the footnotes, it is always from LTR.

Now I know how to move the footnote seperater, that I did. However each footnote is still going from right to left. So I do into footnote styles, the format paragaph, however the option right to left is grey. Like this pic:
[image]

Comment: From my experience, changing the direction of the Footer Style works fine - and so does Ctrl+LShift/RShift also works.

Comment: In the footer style the right direction was also grey. I know the shortcut ctrl rShift, but I want it to automatically be from right to left. Thanks

Comment: Try updating the style based on the current line (after Ctrl+RShifting it).